# What does the [SomeClass self] syntax do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, self

I am currently studying the sample code provided by Apple for Sketch and I stumbled upon some syntax that I haven't seen before. 
It's in `SKTGraphicView.m` in the function `moveSelectedGraphicsWithEvent:`

```
NSRect selBounds = [[SKTGraphic self] boundsOfGraphics:selGraphics];
```

I have never seen the `[SomeClass self]` syntax before. In this case `self` is a subclass of `NSView` and `boundsOfGraphics:` is a class method for `SKTGraphic` which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using self in class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028549/using-self-in-class-method)

Comment: This question is different than that one. This is asking about a call to the `-[NSObject self]` method, not the use of the self "keyword" as it is normally used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `self` method is defined in the `NSObject` *protocol*, so every object be it an instance of a class or a class object (of type `Class`) supports the method. It simply returns the object it is called on, i.e. something like:

```
- (id) self { return self; }
```

So `self` on an instance returns the instance, and on a class object returns the class object.

The following therefore holds: `[x self] == x` is `YES` for all instance and class objects `x`

And your line is equivalent to:

```
NSRect selBounds = [SKTGraphic boundsOfGraphics:selGraphics];
```

So that is *what it does*. As to why Apple wrote it this way, that's a different question...